# ClassCastException when sending email under servicemix using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-servicemix

I'm sending email with attachments under servicemix using the JavaMail API. I'm using the same code that works stand-alone, and I get a strange exception:

> Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-5" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
>   com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed  at
>   org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation.OsgiMailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(Osg
>   iMailcapCommandMap.java:60)

I've tried a lot of tricks, including importing package com.sun.mail.handlers in the bundle definition and those described [in this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-69180.html).

The project is java 1.5 code run by JDK 1.5, FuseESB 4.2

-- **edit** --

The problem was caused by weblogic.jar loaded into servicemix, which provided own copies of mailcap and other files from java mail api and activation, exposed via META_INF.

Comment: What is the class name of the class you are getting?

Comment: I tried to get around this too, but couldn't locally. For whatever reason, I could not get the MimeMultipart to work, even in Java SE 6. I even tried with and without the activation.jar from Sun/Oracle. Interested to know what others say works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a conflicted Class case.

> ab.jar has Class AB
>
> cd.jar also has Class AB

And then your application run with classpath including ab.jar and cd.jar.
Java load Class AB from ab.jar, but actually the correct Class to be loaded is AB from cd.jar.

Perhaps you can try searching the jar files for conflicted classes. Can be done easily by if you are using Eclipse. Include all jars to project's build path and then press: CTRL+SHIFT+T (shortcut for Open Type), key in: multipart_mixed and see how many jars have it.

Could also conflict with activation.jar in java runtime library.

Comment: Just having the same class in two jars on the classpath won't cause a ClassCastException.

Comment: If AB from ab.jar and AB from cd.jar has exactly the same packages name but different version of code, then it might cause a ClassCastException.

Comment: No, it can't. You can only get a CCE between two classes of the same name if those classes are loaded by different ClassLoaders.

Comment: It was partially the case you described. The problem was mailcap and other files exposed in META_INF directory by weblogic.jar. The solution was to remove this files.